# Connect Grails to Autonomous ORACLE database

Tags: oracle, grails, oracle-autonomous-db

I want to connect my grails server to an autonomous ORACLE database but when using the following configuration as dataSource:

```
dataSource {
            dbCreate = "none"
            driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//tns_name?TNS_ADMIN=/home/wallet"
            username = "username"
            password = "password"
            schema = ""
            dialect = "com.flosslab.egrocery.dialect.Oracle10gDialectExtended"
            properties {
                ....
            }
        }
```

I keep receiving this error.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified
```

It works on sqplus when I put the wallet folder under $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin and then type
`sqlplus username/password@tns_name`

Maybe I am missing something in the dataSource configuration ?

Comment: Does `jdbc:oracle:thin:@tns_name?TNS_ADMIN=/home/wallet` work?

Comment: This is the new error: IO Error: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"

Comment: "Invalid connection string format, a valid format is" - Interesting.  I have not used Oracle Autonomous but their docs at https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/connecting-to-oracle-autonomous-database-via-jdbc use `jdbc:oracle:thin:@todos_tpurgent` as a JDBC url.  I am sorry that I cannot help.  Best of luck!